# Is there a projective bundle formula for Deligne cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, complex-manifolds

Given a projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E) \to X$ on a complex manifold $X$, is there a projective bundle formula for Deligne cohomology? That is, can Deligne cohomology $H_D^n(\mathbb{P}(E),\mathbb{Z}(n))$ be decomposed into Deligne cohomology $H_D^i(X,\mathbb{Z}(j))$ for $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes. See for instance J. Grivaux, *Chern classes in Deligne cohomology for coherent analytic sheaves*. Math. Ann. 347 (2010), no. 2, 249-284.